# Return the row where grouped condition is met

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas data frame, `raw_data`,  and I am trying to identify the `day` where the max `value` happens within each group of `Well_ID` when `Dist < std` on day 2 and 4.

In other words, if `Dist < std`, return `day` where the max `value` is observed for each `WellID` to get the following:

- Well A: Day 4
- Well B:  Day 2

This is what `raw_data` looks like:

| WellID | Dist | std | day | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 3.2 | 8 | 1 | 282 |
| A | 9.6 | 8 | 2 | 600 |
| A | 4.1 | 8 | 3 | 56 |
| A | 7.4 | 8 | 4 | 295 |
| A | 12.0 | 8 | 5 | 312 |
| B | 2.3 | 10 | 1 | 203 |
| B | 4.7 | 10 | 2 | 212 |
| B | 18.1 | 10 | 3 | 365 |
| B | 3.5 | 10 | 4 | 202 |

Is it possible to chain all of this together as I am trying to do here?

```py
final_data['peak_day'] = raw_data.groupby('Well_ID').agg(max('value')).where(raw_data['dist']<raw_data['std'])['Day']
```

You can replicate the example with this code:

```py
raw_data = pd.DataFrame({'WellID':['A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B'],
                         'Dist':[3.2,9.6,4.1,7.4,12,2.3,4.7,18.1,3.5],
                         'std':[8,8,8,8,8,10,10,10,10],
                         'day':[1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4],
                         'value':[282,600,56,295,312,203,212,365,202]})
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are only interested in rows where `Dist < std`, I suggest you input that condition before grouping. Then, you can use `idxmax`, which returns the index where a condition is met.

```py
# Declare mask because the name `raw_data` is too long for my liking
m = (raw_data['Dist'] < raw_data['std'])
# Get indices where condition is met
idx = raw_data[m].groupby('WellID')['value'].idxmax().values.tolist()
# Get the days of these indices
raw_data.iloc[idx][['WellID','day']]

  WellID  day
3      A    4
6      B    2
```